# rails 3 paperclip watermark

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Im looking for a watermark processor which works with filenames contains whitespaces and non alfanum chars. On the internet I have found bunch of classes but no one works correctly.

best regards

Comment: have you tried using rmagick after upload on the model?

Comment: no, I dont know how to do this :|